# How do you animate rows swapping with ListView? (React Native)

Tags: listview, reactjs, react-native, layout-animation

I'm trying to animate the swapping of two rows with a React Native ListView

Here's my datasource code (both in my render method):

```
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1.id !== r2.id})
var dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(state.todoLists[this.props.index].todos.slice())
```

Here's my swap code (using MobX):

```
    var {todo, i} = forID(state.todoLists[list].todos, id) //Gets index and todo from  id
    state.todoLists[list].todos.splice(i, 1)
    state.todoLists[list].todos.push({...todo, done: !todo.done})
```

As you can see, the equivalence is persisted since the array item is just shifted down.

If I try LayoutAnimation, I get this weirdness:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please add the code you are using to update the DataSource?  It will help diagnose the issue a bit.

Comment: @DanHorrigan Added my datasource, let me know if you need more!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is the fact that (according to what you say) you are creating the DataSource in your `render` method.  You should create the `ListView.DataSource` object in your constructor (or `componentWillMount`), then call `cloneWithRows` when your data changes, not in `render`.  The issue is that by recreating a new DataSource on each render, it never calls the `rowHasChanged` function because there is never a previous state in the datasource.

**Example Correct Implementation**

In the below example, I setup the datasource in the constructor and store it in the state.  Then once mounted, I have it load the todos, and update the datasource in the state, which will trigger a re-render.

Then, when you want to move a todo to the bottom, you would call `this.moveItemToBottom(id)`, which modifies the state, and updates the datasource on the state, and re-render after setting up the LayoutAnimation.

```js
class TodoList extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      ds: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => (r1 !== r2),
      }),
    }; 
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    loadInitialData();
  }
  
  loadInitialData() {
    // Do something to get the initial list data
    let todos = someFuncThatLoadsTodos();

    this.setState({
      ds: this.state.ds.cloneWithRows(todos),
    });
  }

  moveItemToBottom(id) {
    // get your state somewhere??
    let todos = state.todoLists[list].todos;

    let {todo, i} = forID(state.todoLists[list].todos, id)
    todos.splice(i, 1).push({...todo, done: !todo.done});
    
    LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
    this.setState({
      ds: this.state.ds.cloneWithRows(todos),
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.ds}
        // Other props
      />
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT/NOTE: My example doesn't take into account anything to do with MobX.  I haven't used it, but from a cursory look, you may need to observe the todos list and update the datasource whenever it updates, and just have the `moveItemToBottom` method update the MobX state and rely on the observable to `setState` with the cloned datasource.

Comment: Hm, I moved the DataSource instantiation to state and left cloneWithRows in my render method, and there was no change.

Comment: Tried switching to your example identically, issue persists. Does your implementation of that behave as expected?